# An $(n, \epsilon)$-spanning set on two-dimensional torus

Tags: dynamical-systems, entropy

Let $T : S^1 \times S^1 \to S^1 \times S^1$, $T(x, y) = (x + \alpha, y + x) \; mod \; 1$. For every $n \in \mathbb{N}$
$$ T^n(x, y) = (x + n \alpha, y  + nx +\frac{n(n-1)}{2} \alpha) \; mod \; 1. $$
I want to calculate the topological entropy of $T$.

How can I find an $(n, \epsilon)$-spanning set?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$
T^n(x,y)-T^n(x',y')=(x-x',y-y'+n(x-x'))\bmod1
$$
is independent of $\alpha$. This shows that $(n,\varepsilon)$-spanning sets are independent of $\alpha$ and so the same goes for the entropy. Now note that the map
$$
T_0(x, y) = (x, y + x)\bmod1
$$
is a toral automorphism having only $1$ has eigenvalue. Hence, $h(T)=h(T_0)=\log 1=0$.